# How to derive the commutation coefficient from coordinate basis (GR)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, commutator, vector-fields

Given two vectors $U$ and $V$
\begin{align}
    [U, V] &= [U^\mu e_{(\mu)}, V^\nu e_{(\nu)}] \tag{1} \label{eq1} \\
           &= [U^\mu e_{(\mu)}(V^\nu) - V^\mu e_{(\mu)}(U^\nu)]e_{(\nu)} + U^\mu V^\nu [e_{(\mu)}, e_{(\nu)}] \tag{2} \label{eq2}
\end{align}

The $[e_{(\mu)}, e_{(\nu)}]$ in eq.\eqref{eq2} is called commutation coefficient. How does eq.\eqref{eq2} derived from eq.\eqref{eq1}? If we expand the eq.\eqref{eq1},

\begin{align}
    [U^\mu e_{(\mu)}, V^\nu e_{(\nu)}] &= U^\mu e_{(\mu)} (V^\nu e_{(\nu)}) - V^\nu e_{(\nu)}(U^\mu e_{(\mu)}) \tag{3} \label{eq3}
\end{align}
where the first term
\begin{equation}
    U^\mu e_{(\mu)} (V^\nu e_{(\nu)})f = U^\mu ((e_{(\mu)}V^\nu) e_{(\nu)}f + U^\mu V^\nu e_{(\mu)}(e_{(\nu)}f)), \tag{4} \label{eq4}
\end{equation}
where $f$ is an arbitrary function and $e_{(\mu)} = \partial_\mu$ and $e_{(\nu)} = \partial_\nu$.

Is the derivation in eq.\eqref{eq3} and eq.\eqref{eq4} correct? I feel so lost how to get eq.\eqref{eq2} from eq.\eqref{eq3} and eq.\eqref{eq4}?

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "a $V^\mu$ term?"

Comment: @Andrew Inside the square bracket of eq.(2), there's a $V^\mu$ term. However, in the commutator of eq.(1), there's only $V^\nu$. Is there a notation change of indices? I could not see.

Comment: All the indices dummy indices, not free indices (meaning, they are being summed over), so it is fine (and common) to relabel the indices, so long as the pattern of index contractions is the same. In other words, $V^\mu e_{(\mu)} = V^\nu e_{(\nu)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the rule how to bring a product out of a commutator:

\begin{align}
[U,V] 
&=[U^u e_u,V^v e_v] \cr
&=U^u[e_u,V^v e_v]+[U^u,V^v e_v]e_u \cr
&=U^uV^v[e_u,e_v] + U^u[e_u,V^v]e_v + V^v[U^u,e_v]e_u 
  +\require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{[U^u,V^v]}e_v e_u  \cr
&=U^uV^v[e_u,e_v] + U^ue_uV^ve_v-U^uV^ve_ue_v + V^vU^ue_ve_u-V^ve_vU^ue_u \cr
&=U^uV^v[e_u,e_v] + (U^u e_u V^v-V^u e_u U^v)e_v + (V^vU^ue_ve_u-U^uV^ve_ue_v) \cr
&=U^uV^v[e_u,e_v] + (U^u e_u V^v-V^u e_u U^v)e_v + \cancelto{0}{(V^uU^v-U^uV^v)}e_ue_v
\end{align}
which is your eqn(2).